# How to Increment in DOM (oneliner)?

Tags: javascript, dom

I know simplest way to do increment in DOM value:

```
let progress = +document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML
progress++
document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = progress
```

is there more elegant way to do it like this ?

`document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML++`

Comment: Do you want to increment the property or the attribute? They're not the same thing.

Comment: For an input element, the `value` attribute is used as the initial default for the property, but the `.value` property is what the user input updates and gets sent to the server.

Comment: I edited my examples, I want to increment innerHTML )) sorry

Comment: Didn't what you suggested work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there more elegant way to do it like this ?
>
> document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML++

First of all, let me explain:

- `++` is an unary operator (so you need only one variable for it - some number)
- `innerHTML` is a string (yes, it is a text)
- if you would add `++` to the string it has interesting consequences: it will try to convert the string to a number, so actually you will result in correct number if your string has number inside, or you will result in `NaN` (not-a-number)

So, yes, we can use a "hack":

```js
(document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML)++; // variant 1
++(document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML); // variant 2
```

It will work if your `progress` element has number in it. Example:

```js
function inc() {
  (document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML)++;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress">0</div>
<button onclick="inc()">Click me</button>
```

But, you know, this is a "hack". I recommend you not to use it like this, but at least, this answers your question.